# SSH stopped working after a server update? What happened?

Tags: openssh

I have been using PKI based SSH connections for over 10 years. Suddenly, after a server update - some of the connections stopped working. I am using the same PKI keys I have used for years (each server has it's own keys, I have a small set of personal keys).

Working - looks like this:

```
C:\Users\michael>ssh2 -p 2222 root@192.168.129.64 date
Authentication successful.
Fri Nov 25 10:30:42  2016
```

Not working looks like:

```
C:\Users\michael>ssh2 root@192.168.129.64 date
warning: Authentication failed.
Disconnected; key exchange or algorithm negotiation failed (Algorithm negotiation failed.).
```

What changed?

Comment: Whenever I upgrade or reconfigure SSH I generally immediately try to open another SSH connection while leaving the current connection open for debugging. That approach would help with debugging in scenarios like yours. Do you still have access to the server? Or are you trying to debug this from the client side with no access to look at server side logs until you have solved the problem?

Comment: I have always had access to the server, fortunately. Generally, when applying updates I try to be 'on the console' - for reasons like you mention. What I tried to show here is how to debug when it works for some (e.g., recent putty), but not others (e.g., 14 year old ssh-client that does not know improved ciphers, kex, and mac algorithms.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After an update - side-effects may come into play. With OpenSSH - defaults change frequently. OpenBSD (who maintain/develop OpenSSH) have a policy of OpenBSD to not be concerned about backwards compatibility. This can 'break' things that are, read were, working well.

There is a massive hint - that I did not notice when this first happened to me (using the GUI interface, and I just clicked it away and 'was angry' with 'stupid update - new version is broken'. Turns out the new version was not broken - but OpenBSD/OpenSSH starting changing the key exchange defaults starting with OpenSSH-6.7p1 see: http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.7, noteably:

> ## Changes since OpenSSH 6.6
>
> Potentially-incompatible changes
>
> - sshd(8): The default set of ciphers and MACs has been altered to
>     remove unsafe algorithms. In particular, CBC ciphers and arcfour*
>     are disabled by default.
>
>   The full set of algorithms remains available if configured
>     explicitly via the Ciphers and MACs sshd_config options.

My problem is I have an old client that does not have any of the new defaults, so it cannot connect.

Two solution paths: fix/patch the server or - fix/patch the client.

Server solution: bring back "old" settings so "old" clients can continue to connect that is, - friendly to existing clients - edit the sshd_config file and add back (enough) of the old ciphers.

The key lines to change/add in sshd_config being:

```
ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-cbc
KexAlgorithms  curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
macs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1
```

Just add:

```
# Ciphers
# The dafaults starting with OpenSSH 6.7 are:
# aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
# older clients may need an older cipher, e.g.
# ciphers aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour
# only adding aes256-cbc as an "old" cipher

ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-cbc

# KEX Key Exchange algorithms
# default from openssh 6.7 are:
# curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,\
#  diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
# an older kex are: none,KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

# only adding diffie-hellman-group-sha1  as an "old" KEX
# and this should be deleted ASAP as it is clearly "one of the problems" with SSL based encryption
KexAlgorithms  curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

# MAC message authentification code
# the new defaults are:
# umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,
# hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-
# etm@openssh.com,
# umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,
# hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512

# older defaults (still supported) are:
# macs hmac-sha1,hmac-md5

# consider removing hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5 "Soon!"
macs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1
```

Solution #2 - fix/replace the client

An easy way to see what ciphers you current client supports (assuming CLI) is `ssh -h` and see if that provides something like:

```
Supported ciphers:
  3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish192-cbc,twofish128-cbc,des-cbc@ssh.com,cast128-cbc,rc2-cbc@ssh.com,arcfour,none
Supported MAC algorithms:
  hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha256@ssh.com,hmac-sha256-96@ssh.com,hmac-ripemd160@ssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-96@ssh.com,hmac-tiger128@ssh.com,hmac-tiger128-96@ssh.com,hmac-tiger160@ssh.com,hmac-tiger160-96@ssh.com,hmac-tiger192@ssh.com,hmac-tiger192-96@ssh.com,none
```

Another useful command is: `ssh -V`

```
ssh2: SSH Secure Shell 3.2.9 Windows Client
Product: SSH Secure Shell for Workstations
License type: none (non-commercial)
```

Mine - was - an very old client - for my desktop. Looking above you can see it does not support any of the - 15 years later - preferred algorithms, not even one -cbr (rotating), only -cbc (block-copy).

If you client does not have an option to provide the keys, etc. supported (OpenSSH should have the option `-Q`) just start a connection to yourself, e.g., `ssh -v localhost` and there are lines such as this to tell you wat is known:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-grousha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysatiu.se
...
```

And what was found (and used):

```
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
```

## Extra: debug info from a failed connect - more details

Or, what was tried, but missed.

```
debug: OpenSSH: Major: 7 Minor: 3 Revision: 0
debug: Ssh2Transport: All versions of OpenSSH handle kex guesses incorrectly.
debug: Ssh2Transport: Algorithm negotiation failed for c_to_s_cipher: client list: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,twofish128-cbc,cast128-cbc,twofish-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish192-cbc,twofish256-cbc,arcfour vs. server list : chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug: Ssh2Transport: Algorithm negotiation failed for s_to_c_cipher: client list: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,twofish128-cbc,cast128-cbc,twofish-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish192-cbc,twofish256-cbc,arcfour vs. server list : chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug: Ssh2Transport: lang s to c: `', lang c to s: `'
debug: Ssh2Transport: Couldn't agree on kex or hostkey alg. (chosen_kex = NULL, chosen_host_key = ssh-rsa)
debug: Ssh2Common: DISCONNECT received: Algorithm negotiation failed.
```

---

Edit: added 02-jan-2017

### New Section - what about keys that stop working?

On my server I have an 'old' client and the 'latest' client installed - and get different behavior connecting to a server. Here the issue is not cipher mis-matches - but use of an *archaic* PKI pair - based on DSA.

In short, openssh-7(.3) no longer sends (by default, maybe not at all) DSA public keys.

Below I compare the output of two versions of openssh
/usr/bin/ssh (old version, left-side) and
/opt/bin/ssh (new version, right-side) - the command is:

```
${version}/ssh -v user@host date
```

As you scan through the output below I hope you notice the steps and messages are generally the same. The key difference comes after the string **SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT**

What I want you to notice is that the old version offers (and is accepted by the 'old' server - the DSA based key pair while the new server never offers the DSA based key.

Note: the 'solution' for this is to add (at least one of) the rsa, ecdsa, or the ed25519 based PKI pairs.

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016                     | OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config        | debug1: Reading configuration data /var/openssh/etc/ssh_confi
debug1: Failed dlopen: /usr/krb5/lib/libkrb5.a(libkrb5.a.so): <
        0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the pat <
                                                              <
debug1: Error loading Kerberos, disabling Kerberos auth.      <
debug1: Connecting to x061 [192.168.129.61] port 22.            debug1: Connecting to x061 [192.168.129.61] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.                                 debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_rsa type 1          debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
                                                              > debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1    debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_dsa type 2          debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
                                                              > debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1    debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 3        debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 3
                                                              > debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -   debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version  | debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0 pat OpenSSH*                       | debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
                                                              > debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
                                                              > debug1: identity file /home/michael/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0            debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0              | debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
                                                              > debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version
                                                              > debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
                                                              > debug1: Authenticating to x061:22 as 'padmin'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent                                   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received                               debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none          | debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none          | debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
                                                              > debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@o
                                                              > debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@o
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT                          debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY                       debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 9f:0a:4d:a8:1b:ba:e6:d4:1a:b2:cd | debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:ORf5UVI7mRm/9MthM2qXM
debug1: Host 'x061' is known and matches the RSA host key.      debug1: Host 'x061' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/michael/.ssh/known_hosts:57          debug1: Found key in /home/michael/.ssh/known_hosts:57
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct                     | debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent                                   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS                              debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
                                                              > debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received                               debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server                         | debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/michael/.ssh/id_dsa - not
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent                         <
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received                        debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey                   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/michael/.ssh/id_rsa      debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/michael/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/michael/.ssh/id_dsa    | debug1: Offering ECDSA public key: /home/michael/.ssh/id_ecds
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 433            | debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA                   | debug1: Trying private key: /home/michael/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).                 | debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Authenticated to x061 ([192.168.129.61]:22).                  | debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]                       | debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com               | padmin@x061's password:
debug1: Entering interactive session.                         |
```

Comment: I also had users here complaining about keys with obsolete protocols by the time I upgraded to Debian 8.

Comment: I forgot to mention - that for my windows I switched to putty (ssh.com only sells to businesses) - would have stayed with `ssh2` if they would have accepted me - mainly for the ease of doing `scp` transfers from the same window as `ssh`

Comment: Update your client instead of using years ancient clients and enabling possibly broken algorithms.

Comment: See [Upgrade your SSH keys!](https://blog.g3rt.nl/upgrade-your-ssh-keys.html) for more details, but as @Jakuje says, it's a bad idea to keep old keys, old clients and old algorithms.

Comment: the age of the key is not an issue, imho - but the type and size. "DSA" is out, "RSA" at least 2048-bit. 'Better' is ecdsa. As @Jakuje mentions - and what this Q&A is about - update clients - but also be updating defaults. As a client you can 'demand' a server uses better algorithms by not offering weak (worse broken) ones.

Comment: too late to change edit: @Stephen Kitt's link prefers ed25519. As far as brute force goes - one recommendation is to change keys every three months. While better - the fallacy is thinking brute force does not succeed on day 1. Not likely - but possible. Nothing is 100% secure.